# Исключение об ошибке биллинга Google Play

Tags: android, kotlin, android-billing

Поскольку в России отменили микро-транзакции внутри приложения, возник вопрос:

Появляется ли какое-либо особое исключение при ошибке от биллинга в подобной ситуации?

Хотелось бы обработать именно момент того, что ошибка возникла по причине данной проблемы.

Comment: а в Нашей Стране ничего не отменяли. Пишите явно.

Comment: @KoVadim указал

Comment: @KoVadim ресурс вроде stackowerflow на русском называется

Comment: @AndreyM всё верно он написал, на русском не означает что он только для россиян. Русскоговорящие люди есть во всём мире :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл. При подобной ошибке billingResult в PurchasesUpdatedListener выдает response code равный 3, что соответствует константе BILLING_UNAVAILABLE. Поэтому если хотите обработать данный вариант - можно отловить его там и обработать